# How to transform json file to multiple Dataframes with Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file that I need to import.

```
{"TableA": [{"code": "x1","value": 120},{"code": "x2","value": 100}],
"TableB": [{"code": "y1","value": 220},{"code": "y2","value": 230}]}
```

And I need to get two DataFrames.

In the end I need to get two different Dataframes like this:

```
>>> a = {'code': ["x1", "x2"], 'value': [120, 100]}
>>> TableA = pd.DataFrame(a)
>>> TableA
  code  value
0   x1    120
1   x2    100

>>> b = {'code': ["y1", "y2"], 'value': [220, 230]}
>>> TableB = pd.DataFrame(b)
>>> TableB
  code  value
0   y1    220
1   y2    230
```

I tried using pd.read_json but and I get:

```
>>> Tables = pd.read_json("TableAB.json")

>>> Tables
                         TableA                        TableB
0  {'code': 'x1', 'value': 120}  {'code': 'y1', 'value': 220}
1  {'code': 'x2', 'value': 100}  {'code': 'y2', 'value': 230}
```

I don't know how to get to the point that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary of DataFrames:

```
d = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in Tables.items()}

print (d['TableA'])
print (d['TableB'])
```

Comment: T = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in Tables.items()}


T["TableA"]
                         TableA
0  {'code': 'x1', 'value': 120}
1  {'code': 'x2', 'value': 100}


Still does not solve the  code and value as columns.